# Testing async/await method. Exception not being caught by Jest in unit test

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm attempting to test some code that uses `await` and `async` using Jest. The problem I'm having is an exception is thrown, but Jest doesn't seem to catch it.

For example, here is `run` method that checks to see if `session.url` is present. If not, an exception is thrown:

```
const args = require('args');
const fs = require('fs');
const { promisify } = require('util');

const readFile = promisify(fs.readFile);

// Loads JSON configuration file
module.exports.loadConfigFile = async (filename) => {
  const contents = await readFile(filename, 'utf8');
  return JSON.parse(contents);
};

// Prepare session ensuring command line flags override config
module.exports.prepareSession = async (flags) => {
  if(!flags.config) return flags;
  const config = await this.loadConfigFile(flags.config);
  return {...config, ...flags};
};

// Runs the race application
module.exports.run = async (flags = {}) => { 
  const session = await this.prepareSession(flags);
  if(!session.url) throw new Error('A valid URL is required');
};
```

Here I test to see if an exception is thrown:

```
describe('Race Module', () => {
  test('Throws exception if no URL is provided', async () => {
    const runner = await race.run();
    expect(runner).toThrowError();
  });

  ...
```

The test runs and it appears an exception is thrown but jest hasn't caught it and it doesn't pass:

```
Race Module
    ✕ Throws exception if no URL is provided (3ms)

● Race Module › Throws exception if no URL is provided

A valid URL is required

  at Object.<anonymous>.module.exports.run (src/race.js:23:27)
      at <anonymous>
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

My initial thought was to chain `catch(() => {})` to `race.run()` in the test but I am not entirely sure how I would test that. That might not even be the problem.

Comment: The `await` throws the exception from the promise that `run()` returns. `runner` would be the result of the promise (the `return` value of your async function)

Comment: Ahhhh! I see now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix was to use `rejects.toThrow`. But, note that this functionality is currently broken in master. I had to use a beta branch. See here: https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/4884

```
test('Throws exception if no URL is provided', async () => {
    await expect(race.run())
      .rejects
      .toThrow('A valid URL is required');
});
```